# Open multiple tabs and execute command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

```
#!/bin/bash

tab="--tab"
cmd="bash -c 'python';bash"
foo=""

for i in 1 2 3; do
      foo+=($tab -e "$cmd")         
done

gnome-terminal "${foo[@]}"

exit 0
```

i'm using this scirpt to open multiple tabs using shell script.

call it `multitab.sh` and execute this way `user@user:~$ sh multitab.sh`

currently this script supposed to open 3 tabs and all of them will execute python command. 
but when i execute it, throws en error

```
multitab.sh: 8: multitab.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

What is the reason of this error? How can I make this script to execute 3 different commands?

I've already gone through. below SOF threads but none of them worked for me.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/315408/open-terminal-with-multiple-tabs-and-execute-application
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/500357/opening-multiple-terminal-tabs-and-running-command
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/521084/bash-script-for-multiple-tabs-program-running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are running the script with `sh`, where the `+=` syntax to add elements is not available:

```
foo+=($tab -e "$cmd")
#  ^^
```

So all you need to do is to run the script with Bash:

```
bash multitab.sh
```

Or just using `./multitab.sh` (after giving executing mode to the file), since the shebang in the script (`#!/bin/bash`) already mentions Bash.

From the Bash Reference Manual:

> #### [Appendix B Major Differences From The Bourne Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell)
>
> - Bash supports the ‘+=’ assignment operator, which appends to the value of the variable named on the left hand side.